# Largest Matrix Matlab Linprog can Support

Tags: matlab

I want to use MATLAB `linprog` to solve a problem, and I check it by a much smaller, much simpler example.

But I wonder if MATLAB can support my real problem, there may be a `300*300*300*300` matrix...

---

Maybe I should give the exact problem. There is a directed graph of network nodes, and I want to get the lowest utilization of the edge capacity under some constraints. Let `m` be the number of edges, and `n` be the number of nodes. There are `mn²` variables and `nm²` constraints. Unfortunately, `n` may reach 300...

I want to use MATLAB `linprog` to solve it. As described above, I am afraid MATLAB can not support it...Lastly the matrix must be sparse, can some way simplify it?

Comment: I used to have 1TB (1000GB!) RAM machine at the lab... You could do `zeros(300,300,300,300);` and still have plenty of room left... these were a happy times...

Comment: @Shai: gimme gimme gimme!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I no longer have access to this incredible machine. but it was like magic.

Comment: amazing...i wish get one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: a `300*300*300*300` array is not called a matrix, but a tensor (or simply array). Therefore you can not use matrix/vector algebra on it, because that is not defined for arrays with dimensionality greater than 2, and you can certainly not use it in `linprog` without some kind of interpretation step.

Second: if I interpret that `300⁴` to represent the number of *elements* in the matrix (and not the size), it really depends if MATLAB (or any other software) can support that.

As already answered by ben, if your matrix is *full*, then the answer is likely to be **no**. `300^4` `doubles` would consume almost 65GB of memory, so it's quite unlikely that any software package is going to be capable of handling that all from memory (unless you actually have > 65 GB of RAM). You could use a [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)-type scheme, where you only load parts of the matrix in memory and leave the rest on harddisk, but that is **insanely slow**. Moreover, if you have matrices *that* huge, it's entirely possible you're overlooking some ways in which your problem can be simplified.

If you matrix is *sparse* (i.e., contains lots of zeros), then maybe. Have a look at MATLAB's [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) command.

So, what exactly is your problem? Where does that enormous matrix come from? Perhaps I or someone else sees a way in which to reduce that matrix to something more manageable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 300*300*300*300 I mean the height(width) of the matrix. and the matrix is sparse...Any way can help me deal this?

Comment: @CPT: Then it will depend on *how* sparse your matrix is...Why don't you just try to construct your real matrix `A` with the `sparse` command, and if that works, then just throw it in `linprog` and see what happens?

Comment: I add some descriptions to my question. I will try your suggestion later, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

On my system, with 24GByte RAM installed, running Matlab R2013a, `memory` gives me:

```
Maximum possible array:     44031 MB (4.617e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     44031 MB (4.617e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:      1029 MB (1.079e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):     24574 MB (2.577e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

On a 64-bit version of Matlab, if you have enough RAM, it should be possible to at least create a full matrix as big as the one you suggest, but whether `linprog` can do anything useful with it in a realistic time is another question entirely.

As well as investigating the use of `sparse` matrices, you might consider working in `single` precision: that halves your memory usage for a start.

Answer (score 0):

well you could simply try: `X=zeros( 300*300*300*300 )`
on my system it gives me a very clear statement:

```
>> X=zeros( 300*300*300*300 )
Error using zeros
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

since `zeros` is a build in function, which only fills a array of the given size with zeros you can asume that handling such a array will not be possible

you can also use the `memory` command

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:     21549 MB (2.260e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     21549 MB (2.260e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:       685 MB (7.180e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):     12279 MB (1.288e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.

>> 2.278e+10 /8   
%max bytes avail for arrays divided by 8 bytes for double-precision real values

ans =
2.8475e+09

>> 300*300*300*300

ans =
8.1000e+09
```

which means I dont even have the memory to store such a array.

while this may not answer your question directly it might still give you some insight.